# Problem understanding the proof of Casorati-Weierstrass- Conway

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I am having trouble understanding why this $m+1$ is coming into the picture. Since $\frac{f(z)-c}{z-a}$ has a pole of order $m$, we have $$ \frac{f(z)-c}{z-a}=\frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^m}$$ for some analytic function $g$. Which implies
$$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)^{m+1}\frac{f(z)-c}{z-a}=\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)^{m}({f(z)-c})=\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)g(z)=0.$$
I am unable to understand why $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)^{m+1}({f(z)-c})=0$ is written .
[image]

Comment: Indeed $m$ would do but $m+1$ doesn't hurt (also it depends on which version of removable singularity criterion you want to use).

Comment: Will the proof be same if we use $m$ instead of $m+1$? Then we would have had $f(z)(z-a)^{m-1}$ with a removable singularity. Can you please explain whether it will work or not?